# iphone xml-rpc utf8 strings

Tags: iphone, cocoa, utf-8, xml-rpc

I'm stuck with getting back data from my server via `XML-RPC`. Why all utf8 strings are look so strange? Especially, I don't understand why one of them (which is 'title') looks in different way in comparision with 'post'?

```
<CFBasicHash 0x568c0e0 [0x14d7400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
 0 : <CFString 0x56378f0 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "title"} = <26233333 3bd0b1d0 b5d0b5d0 b5>
 1 : <CFString 0x568a300 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "id"} = <CFNumber 0x568c780 [0x14d7400]>{value = +15, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
 2 : <CFString 0x568cee0 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "time"} = <CFString 0x568cfa0 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "1295372714"}
 3 : <CFString 0x568d230 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "post"} = <CFString 0x568d310 [0x14d7400]>{contents = "\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0435\u043c \u0432\u0435\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0430\u0440\u043c\u044f\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u043a"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting a dictionary back from the server?

Try something like:

```
NSData *data; // THIS IS YOUR RETURNED SERVER DATA

NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSError *error;

dictionary = (NSDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization
                               propertyListFromData:data;
                                   mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                             format:NULL
                                   errorDescription:&error];

if (!dictionary)
{
   NSLog(error);
   [error release];
}
else
{
   NSLog(dictionary);
}
```

Think you should release the dictionary when you've finished with it:

```
[dictionary release];
```

See [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Cheers mate. I'm getting back NSDictionary, I don't know what I should do with encoding.

Comment: I mean, that I don't understand why both utf8 strings look different. One of them looks proper utf8 \uNNNN, and other one completely different. I use [NSString stringWithUTF8String]; but, now I'm struggling with strings which is just english, becuase this code crash my app.

Comment: You'll need to post more info about what and how you're retrieving the server data?  It's your server, and in any case it is possible to inspect the encoding from the returning URL header?